# Android layout organization

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some general question about layouts in my application I ma trying to make. I have attached a screenshot of how this is suppose to look like. There are 2 headers at the top (search bar with back button), another list of properties (Crag, Grade...). Then we have vertical scrollable table layout.

[image]

This is little bit of beginner question, but what layouts would I use to create such page, for example something like this (of course this would need to go in more details to handle all information, but as in rough layout?

```
<Relative layout>

<Frame layout>  search bar </Frame layout> 

<Frame layout>  list of properties (Crag, Grade...) </Frame layout> 

<Table layout> vertical scrollable </Table layout>

</Relative layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
<LinearLayout orientation=vertical>

<Toolbar>  search bar </Toolbar> 

<LinearLayout orientation=horizontal>  list of properties (Crag, Grade...) </LinearLayout> 

<RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why would I use Toolbar and how to align LinearLayout  below Toolbar?

Comment: Because in design you have back button and also search button which toolbar handles easily.